# Do html and php use the same css file?

Tags: php, html, css

for example: you created a website and in that website you want to create a login page using php. Do you use the css file that you design your website with, to design login page?

Comment: That's completely up to you. If you want to use the same CSS file, you link it in your PHP file. If you want to use a different file, you link that one. If you want to use both, you link both.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single CSS page to style your whole website if you want to . You will just have to make sure you load in every html file that you load in the browser.

I would suggest splitting this up css file into parts if you expect your application to grow bigger.

Answer (score 0):

PHP actually runs on the server and it renders html (usually).

So if the template you're rendering with php has the same css file included you could use the same css for both pages.

Now for your needs, the login page has possibly some css that your other pages don't need. I would suggest creating a common.css file with everything that both pages will have and another with the login page specific styles.

I hope that's what your looking for.